# Adding AJAX success/error message to Formcarry

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm developing my first website on it. I need to make a contact form, and since it was tough for me to make it from scratch I used Formcarry and connected it with my React App. Now I need to make AJAX success and error messages but I didn't had much luck with it.

**React:**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";


class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: "", surname: "", email: "", message: ""};
  }

  handleForm = e => {
    axios.post(
      "https://formcarry.com/s/LxMYb0c7kXC", 
      this.state, 
      {headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}}
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    e.preventDefault();
  }

  handleFields = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <form id="ajaxForm" onSubmit={this.handleForm}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={this.handleFields} />

        <label htmlFor="surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" onChange={this.handleFields} />

        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleFields} />

        <label htmlFor="message">Your Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" onChange={this.handleFields}></textarea>

        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

**Then I tried adding jQuery to index.html in the public folder:**

```
   $("#ajaxForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: href,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                if(response.status == "success"){
                    alert("We received your submission, thank you!");
                }else{
                    alert("An error occured: " + response.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

After adding jQuery the success and error message isn't showing, am I doing it wrong?

Tho, the email is being sent and that part works correctly.

**I have my website up on heroku:**

https://trustmypetsitter.herokuapp.com/contactpage

Comment: Don't mix jQuery event binding with React. Use React event binding.

Comment: Can you give me a hand with it? Im new to it so I used jQuery

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component

Comment: thanks Ill try something and I hope if I need help I can post another comment with what I did?

Answer (score 0):

axios doesn't returns the response with `response`, you need to use this

```
console.log(response.data);
```

so in order to handle success and error messages properly, use this:

```
handleForm = e => {
    axios.post(
      "https://formcarry.com/s/LxMYb0c7kXC", 
      this.state, 
      {headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}}
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        const { data } = response;

        if(data.status == "success"){
            // handle success
        }
        else{
            // handle formcarry error
            console.log(data.message)
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle network error
        console.log(error);
      });

    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

hope it helps!